# grid layout doesn't work

Tags: html, css

i'm writing this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #gridcontainer {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
            grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gridcontainer">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

i'm suppose to get something like that:
1    2

3    4

but what i get is:
1
2
3
4

it's like the `display:grid` is completely ignored.
What is that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using? Is it up-to-date? The support for the new CSS Grid specification is limited and requires flag activation even in the most recent Chrome.

Please check the browser support in [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: i'm using internet explorer 11 and chrome version 55.0.2883.87, I don't that this is the problem.

Comment: @cabeloblanco I understand the issue was indeed the browser and/or flag activation. Is it working correctly now?